# Entendo que o método post está chegando errado no postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

Meu controller

```
package br.com.clinicamedica.controller.especialidade;

import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.CONFLICT;
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.OK;
import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import br.com.clinicamedica.core.EspecialidadesException;
import br.com.clinicamedica.core.especialidades.EspecialidadesConsultaService;
import br.com.clinicamedica.core.especialidades.EspecialidadesService;
import br.com.clinicamedica.core.especialidades.resource.EspecialidadeListaResource;
import br.com.clinicamedica.core.especialidades.resource.EspecialidadesResource;
import br.com.clinicamedica.utilitario.mensagem.Mensagem;
import lombok.extern.apachecommons.CommonsLog;

@CommonsLog
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/especialidades")
public class EspecialidadeController {

    @Autowired
    private EspecialidadesService especialidadesService;
    @Autowired
    private EspecialidadesConsultaService especialidadesConsultaService;
    private Collection<Mensagem> mensagens;

    @PostMapping(value = "/incluir", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> incluir(EspecialidadesResource resource) {
        mensagens = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            EspecialidadesResource retorno = especialidadesService.incluir(resource, mensagens);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(retorno, OK);
        } catch (EspecialidadesException e) {
            Mensagem m = e.getMensagens().iterator().next();
            log.error(m.toString(), e);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMensagens().iterator().next(), CONFLICT);
        }
    }
}
```

No **Postman**, quando faço assim, não funciona, por ser um metodo post, não deveria passar o objeto ?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Mas chega vazio**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No **Postman**, quando faço assim, funciona, este exemplo não seria de um método **get** ?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os métodos **GET** estão funcionando normal.

> ```
>   @GetMapping(value = "/buscarPeloId", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
>   public ResponseEntity<?> buscarPeloId(Long id) {
>       EspecialidadesResource retorno = especialidadesConsultaService.buscarPeloId(id);
>       return new ResponseEntity<>(retorno, OK);
>   }
> ```

O que pode ser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente o que está faltando para você é indicar o Header do seu POST:

1. Ao lado da aba **Body**, selecione **Headers**.
2. Em **Key**, escreva `Content-Type`.
3. Em **Value**, escreva `application/json`.
4. Envie o seu POST.

[image: Como deve estar no Postman]

O `Content-Type` deve ser indicado como `application/json` para que o backend consiga interpretar corretamente a requisição. Conforme [documentação MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type):

> O cabeçalho Content-Type é utilizado para indicar o tipo de arquivo do
>   recurso.
>
> Em requisições, como POST ou PUT, o client diz ao servidor qual o tipo
>   de dado que está, de fato, sendo enviado.

Comment: Obrigado é isso mesmo

Foi ajustado e está funcionando.

Correria e acaba esquecendo de algumas coisas

Comment: @GuilhermeCostaLopes tendo em vista que essa resposta é uma solução para sua dúvida, por favor, marque-a como resposta clicando no "check" que fica abaixo dos votos positivo/negativo. Isso auxilia outras pessoas a saberem que o problema foi resolvido e não percam tempo tentando resolvê-lo novamente ou que possam tentar utilizar a solução caso tenham um problema similar. Reparei que você não fez isso nas suas outras perguntas também, aconselho de fazê-lo caso alguém tenha dado a solução :)

Comment: Feito e obrigado pela ajuda,